# How can one have multiple panes in CoqIDE?

Tags: coq, coqide

How does one use CoqIDE with more than 2 panes? The code can get really large and its hard to keep track of every definition etc in one pane.

I googled this:

http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~apt/coq_hints.html

but it wasn't too helpful...